# Problem with adding record to database after seeds in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I add test records to the database using seeds

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('categories')->insert([
        ['id' => 1,'name' => 'Select a category', 'slug' => null],
        ['id' => 2,'name' => 'Computers', 'slug' => 'computer-&-office'],
    ]);
}
```

But then, if I want to add a new record to the database, already through the form, I get the error

```
SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "categories_pkey"
```

I understand that when I add a new record through the form, it is created with id = 1, and I already have this id in the database. How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove id from insert() and make it auto increment in mysql,

Answer (score 0):

It complains about a unique constraint, meaning your primary key is indexed as "categories_pkey" or you have another field that is unique.

This happens because you are inserting a record and a record already exists where that column must be unique.

In general production workflow, when you add a record you never specify an ID. Most cases (there are exceptions) ID is an autoincrement integer, meaning it adds up automatically. On the first insert the database set its ID to 1, the second to 2 and so on.

As a seeder, its generally a good idea to set up the ID so you know that a certain ID matches a certain item (as a base content of a project like user states or roles).

As a regular workflow (from a form submission), you can have something like this

```
DB::table('categories')->insert([
        ['name' => 'some value', 'slug' => 'some slug']
]);
```

However, I don't advise to use DB::table when Laravel provides ActiveRecords pattern (ORM, called Eloquent) which you should take a look here.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#introduction

Besides the benefits of layer abstraction and working with activerecords,  It produces a much cleaner code like

```
$data = ['slug' => 'some slug', 'name' => 'some name'];
Category::create($data);
```